# How do I uncompress compressed request data in Koa.js at server side?

Tags: node.js, koa, koa2

I am developing an  HTTP driven REST based application where the need of the project is such that I have to receive compressed **gzipped JSON data** at the **server side**. There are several modules available which demonstrate to compress response and sending them back but I didn't find anything which shows **how to decompress request data received at the server.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this might work out of the box with [`koa-bodyparser`](https://github.com/koajs/bodyparser). Under the hood `koa-bodyparser` uses `co-body` to parse the request body and `co-body` [uses the `inflate` package to inflates the request body before parsing](https://github.com/cojs/co-body/blob/master/lib/json.js#L41).

The following code:

```
const koa = require('koa');
const app = new koa();
const bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser');

app.use(bodyParser());

app.use(function(ctx) {
  ctx.body = ctx.request.body.test;
})

app.listen(3000);
```

and the following request

```
curl \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Encoding: gzip' \
  -XPOST \
  --data-binary @data.json.gz \
  localhost:3000
```

with a data.json that was gzipped (raw looks like the below):

```
{
  "test": "data"
}
```

Everything worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would definitely check it out

Comment: I thought I will have to parse buffer and then decompress the request. Thanks for telling me that co-body supports inflation out of the box, which I didn't know. By the way, I have been directly using co-body in all my koa programs so I didn't use koa-bodyparser, hope that is not considered bad practice.